# Is there a recent pytest alternative with simple "assert"?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use something like pytest for very basic testing using simple **asserts**. Is pytest the best choice for this or are there better recent alternatives?

Comment: Since you seem to want very lightweight testing, why not just use `assert`?

Comment: Why do you want an alternative? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @ChristianDean `pytest` internally rewrite asserts to produce rather detailed and beautiful tracebacks. Very convenient for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

pytest works great for simple testing.

```
def foo():
    return (1,2,3)

def test_foo():
    assert foo() == (1,2,3)
```

Not sure how to make that simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Two aspects to this -
As far as actual alternative testing libraries, `pytest` is pretty much the industry standard with no clear competitors. I cannot find any other testing frameworks with the "simple `assert`" style api.

Now, if you're looking for something even *more* minimalist than `pytest`, `assert` is actually a [python builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), you could write your own miniature runner:

```py
def run_tests(**test_fns):
     failures = dict()
     for test_name, test_fn in test_fns.items():
         try:
             test_fn()
         except Exception as e:
             failures[test_name] = e
     return failures

def failing_test():
     assert False, 'failing test failed'

run_tests(fail=failing_test)
#> {'fail': AssertionError('failing test failed')}
# then maybe pretty print the failures and exit properly
```

You might also consider [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) if you're trying to avoid 3rd party libraries as it's included in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, `py.test` is still the business!